# C++ string::rfind time complexicity

Tags: c++, string

What is time complexity of `string::rfind` method in c++?
From what I understood, rfind is reversing the string and then doing `string::find`. Am I correct? Then it should be O(n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you are not correct. `rfind` searches from the back of the string without reversing the string. The complexity is the same as for a forward `find`.

I haven't found anything in the standard *requiring* this, but any search algorithm that you can use for `find` (like a naive search or a Boyer-Moore / Boyer-Moore-Horspool search) can also be used for `rfind` - so I find it *highly unlikely* that any library implementors would choose a less effective algorithm for their `rfind` implementation.

Comment: is complexitiy of `std::string::find` actually specified? Its not mentioned on cppreference. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No, it's not specified that I can see either (I did a quick browse through the standard too). Added a note about that.